# Получение каждой цифры отдельно из строки

Tags: php

как можно брать цифры в строке полученную из базы "1,5,7" засунуть их в переменные или как то еще лучше чтоб типа в цикле поставить на каждую цифру свои слова которые также в базе типа  селект фрукты вере айди = 5; и так в цикле на каждую

Comment: какая СУБД и версия? зы: зачем делать такую структуру БД и определять формат хранения данных таким образом, что это в дальнейшем подобные проблемы создает? Если имеется отношение многие-ко-многим, то хранить его надо отдельной таблице, а не в виде значений через запятую, если по данным значениям предполагаются выборки. Вернее сказать, не надо загонять это в строку до тех пор, пока этого по каким то редким причинам не по потребует логика предметной области и сам описываемый бизнес-процесс.

Comment: Если мне надо хранить жанры фильмов как я это сделаю?  типа строка 1 жанр такой-то есть строка 2 жанр другой  нет. типа так?

Comment: и да база просто хранит в виде строки никаких связей нет

Comment: есть фильм, есть жанр. очевидно что связь многие-ко-многим в предметной области есть. Очевидно так же, что архитектура вашей БД не соответствует предметной области. у вас должно быть не две таблица жанры/фильмы, а три и в третьей будет как раз хранится связь. Приведите реляционную/физическую модель в соответствие инфологической. Создайте таблицу описания связи и наполните ее. Не занимайтесь ерундой с хранением жанров фильма в виде строки.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
$a = getGeners(3);
$a=strtr($a,array(','=>''));
for($i = 0; $i <= iconv_strlen($a); $i++){
    echo  $a{$i}.'<br>';
}
```

вот ответ. сначала удаляем запятые, потом обращаемся к каждому элементу строки в цикле

Comment: А двузначных чисел в вашем мире ещё не придумали?

Comment: Ну, если уж решили строку использовать, то хотя бы воспользуйтесь стандартной функцией PHP explode(), что ли. А то действитель, не то что "велосипед" - "сандали" изобретаете...

Comment: Я, конечно, понимаю, что вы крутые прогеры но лучше примеры бы(

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php. 
`$values = explode(',', getGeners(3)); 
foreach ($values as $index) { 
echo $dictionary[$index], '<br />';}`

Answer (score 2):

Обычно такие вещи делаются на уровне базы данных, что позволяет:

1. задействовать всю мощь СУБД для операций с данными;
2. разрешить описанные Вами проблемы на уровне запроса к БД.

Пример из реальной жизни (весьма обрезанный):

```sql
CREATE TABLE genres (
 id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT "Наименование жанра",
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE media_objects (
 id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 item_type enum("container", "element") NOT NULL DEFAULT "element" COMMENT "Тип элемента - контейнер, конечный элемент (передача)",
 parent_id int UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT "ID родительского элемента-контейнера",
 epg_id bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT "ID оригинального элемента программы передач",
 category_id tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT "ID категории",
 title varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT "Название",
 desciption TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT "Описание",
 episode int UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT "Номер серии",
 channel_id smallint UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT "ID канала",
 duration int UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Длительность",
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE media_objects_genres (
 media_object_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT "ID медиаобъекта",
 genre_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT "ID жанра",
 `order` tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Порядок сортировки жанров для медиаобъекта",
 FOREIGN KEY (media_object_id) REFERENCES media_objects(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Таблица media_objects_genres в данном случае представляет нам связь типа "многие-ко-многим" между таблицей медиаобъектов ("фильмов") и справочником жанров, которых у "фильма" может быть и ни одного, и несколько. Запрос "получить все наименования жанров для фильма" выглядит примерно так:

```sql
SELECT b.name
FROM media_objects_genres AS a LEFT JOIN genres AS b ON (a.genre_id=b.id)
WHERE a.media_obect_id=123
ORDER BY a.`order`;
```

Такое хранение данных, например, позволяет также сделать и обратную выборку - всех фильмов по жанру - достаточно просто:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
 b.id AS id,
 b.title AS name
FROM media_objects_genres AS a LEFT JOIN media_objects AS b ON (a.media_object_id=b.id)
WHERE a.genre_id=5 AND b.item_type="element"
ORDER BY b.title;
```

а также и более сложные выборки данных по многим параметрам. Ведь именно для этого и создана СУБД, именно это и есть её "хлеб". Если уж использовать СУБД, то в чем смысл делать в программе кодом то, что лучше всего умеет делать именно СУБД?

P.S. "Если мне надо хранить жанры фильмов как я это сделаю? типа строка 1 жанр такой-то есть строка 2 жанр другой нет. типа так? – Gradusnik 1 час назад" - типа как-то так...

Comment: Это всё круто наверное но не мой уровень. Я из всего этого понял не много

Comment: Ну что Вам сказать на это? Могу только порекомендовать повысить уровень. Для начала подойдет, думаю, вот это - https://webbooks.com.ua/books-main/phpmysql/php-7-v-podlinnike-igor-simdyanov-dmitrij-koterov-pdf-2016/ Доходчиво, с примерами, шаг за шагом. Когда-то сам читал, правда еще про 5-й. И по MySQL - настоятельно рекомендую http://www.dialektika.com/books/978-5-8459-1167-4.html, тоже с примерами и шаг за шагом. И самое главное - не забывайте про https://www.php.net/manual/ru/, там куча примеров практического применения кописываемых функций, классов и т.д.